# Heroku fails to precompile assets

Tags: heroku, compilation

I'm trying to push to heroku and its saying  Precompiling assets failed. and i've added `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false`
in the `config/application.rb` file and i ran a migration i'm not sure what to do

```
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.3
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.0.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/...
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rails-assets.org/...
remote:        Using rake 12.3.3
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
remote:        Using minitest 5.11.3
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Using builder 3.2.3
remote:        Using erubi 1.8.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
remote:        Using crass 1.0.4
remote:        Using rack 2.0.7
remote:        Using nio4r 2.4.0
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.4
remote:        Using mini_mime 1.0.2
remote:        Using arel 9.0.0
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.3
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using msgpack 1.3.1
remote:        Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
remote:        Using ffi 1.11.1
remote:        Using bundler 2.0.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Using method_source 0.9.2
remote:        Using thor 0.20.3
remote:        Using pg 1.1.4
remote:        Using popper_js 1.11.1
remote:        Using puma 3.12.1
remote:        Using rails-assets-tether 1.4.7
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.9
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.2.0
remote:        Using i18n 1.6.0
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.5
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.10.4
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.7.1
remote:        Using rack-test 1.1.0
remote:        Using mail 2.7.1
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.2
remote:        Using marcel 0.3.3
remote:        Using bootsnap 1.4.4
remote:        Using rb-inotify 0.10.0
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 9.6.1
remote:        Using uglifier 4.1.20
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.2.0
remote:        Using loofah 2.2.3
remote:        Using activesupport 5.2.3
remote:        Using sass-listen 4.0.0
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.2.0
remote:        Using globalid 0.4.2
remote:        Using activemodel 5.2.3
remote:        Using sass 3.7.4
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.9.1
remote:        Using actionview 5.2.3
remote:        Using activejob 5.2.3
remote:        Using activerecord 5.2.3
remote:        Using actionpack 5.2.3
remote:        Using bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha6
remote:        Using actioncable 5.2.3
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.2.3
remote:        Using activestorage 5.2.3
remote:        Using railties 5.2.3
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
remote:        Fetching simple_form 4.1.0
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.3.5
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.7
remote:        Using rails 5.2.3
remote:        Installing simple_form 4.1.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 23 Gemfile dependencies, 66 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Bundle completed (5.10s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
remote:        Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Uglifier::Error: Unexpected line terminator
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:234:in `parse_result'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:216:in `run_uglifyjs'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.20/lib/uglifier.rb:168:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_a5c613e73cd75dee9abde115bd1676ff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
```

I'm not sure where its tracing to but i dont think yarn has anything to do with it does it?

Comment: Did you notice this line: `remote:        Yarn executable was not detected in the system.`

Comment: I did, i tried adding yarn and all i can find is running brew yarn install and my mac won't recognize brew command

Comment: yes i tried adding yarn but like i said, brew won't work and i cant find another way to add it